# java.util.NoSuchElementException on Arraylist while

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop, iterator

Trying to find broken links from page, for this I am fetching all the available links from web page and then through loop checking one by one, but getting the following error. Not getting any ideal please help me to solve this error.

Below mentioned is my code:

```
                List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.println("Total no. of links are: "+ links.size());
            java.util.Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){

                url = it.next().getAttribute("href");
                urlname=it.next().getText();

                if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(urlname +" - "+url+ ": URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
                    continue;
                }

               /* if(!url.startsWith(homePage)){
                  System.out.println("URL belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
                  continue;
                } */

                try {
                    huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());                       
                    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");                       
                    huc.connect();                      
                    respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

                    if(respCode >= 400){
                        System.out.println(urlname +" - "+ url +": is a broken link");
                    }
                    else{
                       // System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Below attached is my stackTrace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at CRM.test2.Search(test2.java:153)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't advance the `Iterator` twice in the same iteration of the loop.

Use a variable to store the next element obtained from the `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    WebElement element = it.next();
    url = element.getAttribute("href");
    urlname =e lement.getText();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it.next() has to only be called once (save it to a variable). Otherwise, it advances to the next element. With your current code you advance 2 times at each while iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following code where you do not need to manage the iterator yourself

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(WebElement element:links){
url = element.getAttribute("href");
urlName = element.getText();
...
...
}
```